# Getting Syntax error when pass date and time in javascript due to colon(:) and space( )

Tags: javascript

I am getting Syntax error in javascript while pass `date and time` as a parameter due to `colon(:)` and `space( )`
For Ex :

```
onClick=popup(02/06/2015,07**:**12:00,53970,SCN,CHB,JPR,02/06/2015 **strong text**07**:**12:00,20);
```

Comment: Thanks for that status report on your current development efforts. Did you have a *question*?

Comment: Yes, i am not able to send 02/06/2015 07:12:00 as parameter

Comment: Its not able to call popup function because of giving syntex error near by colon(:) and space( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick = popup('02/06/2015','07:12:00',53970,'SCN','CHB','JPR','02/06/2015 07:12:00',20);
```

Pass them as strings.

And since you are using these as URL parameters, Please encode them using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
urlParam = encodeURIComponent(urlParam);
```

Comment: After passing i am getting error near '3 in '31/05/2015 07:12:00'
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

popup('31/05/2015','07:12:00','53970','SCN','CHB','JPR','31/05/2015 07:12:00'

Comment: My popup function code is a simple
function 

popup(deptDt,depttm,busServiceNo,bus_type_cd,fromstop,tostop,brd_TM,route_no1){   
 dhtmlmodal.open("option","iframe","${siteGlobals.siteUrl}ticket_booking/ticket_booking.do?method=seat_layout_view&deptDt="+deptDt+"&busServiceNo="+busServiceNo+"&bus_type_cd="+bus_type_cd+"&depttm="+depttm+"&fromstop="+fromstop+"&tostop="+tostop+"&brd_TM="+brd_TM+"&route_no="+route_no1,'Seat Layout','width=160,height=410,toolbar=0,scroll=no,location=0,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=0,left=620,top=10');
        
    }